# What are some antonyms for salvation?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, terminology, antonyms, dictionaries

I'm writing an essay on how immigrants came to the US in the 1900s for salvation, but instead, they got the opposite. However, I'm looking for a more complex word; it'll sound boring if I just say it was the opposite of what they expected.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas the pilgrim fathers three centuries earlier may have sought religious salvation , many immigrants in the 1900s sought economic salvation: being saved from the economic dangers of starvation and unemployment.

> *salvation* = being saved from danger, loss, or harm
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/salvation)

In your context, the appropriate antonym is therefore not religious but socio-economic.

Of the many words, I suggest  *privation*

> *privation* = a lack of the basic things that are necessary for an acceptable standard of living
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/privation)

You might also consider destitution, indigence, poverty, and hardship.

Answer (score 0):

***damnation:*** (in Christian belief) condemnation to eternal punishment in hell. [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/damnation)

> *sins that risk eternal **damnation***

***perdition:*** (in Christian theology) a state of eternal punishment and damnation into which a sinful and unpenitent person passes after death. [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/perdition)

> *Hence, if the children suffer eternal **perdition** because their parents, who are themselves Christians, do not teach them how to attain salvation, God will judge and punish the parents.*

***reprobation:***  (Theology) the state of being damned [(Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reprobation)

> *Praise be to God,..who decrees election to some and **reprobation** to others.*

***doom:*** fate, lot, irrevocable destiny. (Usually of adverse fate; rarely in good sense); final fate, destruction, ruin, death. (OED)

> *Both the Cardinal and his enemies knew that the minister's **doom** was sealed.*